# Is there an example how to use SWIG to generate C++ buidings with go build?

Tags: c++, go, swig, build-system

I want to build my project with "go build". I've not found any documentation how to integrate swig with the go build process. And also very important, it should be a C++ example C is easy.

#### foo.swig

```
/* foo.i */
%module foo
%{
#include "foo.h"
%}
%include "foo.h"
```

#### foo.h

```
#pragma once
int foo(int a, int b);
class MyClass {
    int a,b,c;
public:
    MyClass(int a, int b, int c): a(a),b(b),c(c) {}
    int foo() {
        return (a+b)*c;
    }
    int bar() {
        return a*(b+c);
    }
};
```

#### foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
int foo(int a, int b){
    return a*b;
}
```

#### main.go

```
package foo
import "fmt"
func main(args []string) {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
    fmt.Println(foo.foo(12, 17))
}
```

#### output

```
arne@ad-X201t ~/g/s/g/k/swig-test> go build
# github.com/krux02/swig-test
In file included from $WORK/github.com/krux02/swig-test/_obj/foo_wrap.c:194:0:
./foo.h:5:1: Fehler: unbekannter Typname: »class«
./foo.h:5:15: Fehler: expected »=«, »,«, »;«, »asm« or »__attribute__« before »{« token
/tmp/go-build724218913/github.com/krux02/swig-test/_obj/foo_wrap.c: In Funktion »_wrap_MyClass_set«:
/tmp/go-build724218913/github.com/krux02/swig-test/_obj/foo_wrap.c:225:3: Fehler: unbekannter Typname: »class«
/tmp/go-build724218913/github.com/krux02/swig-test/_obj/foo_wrap.c:226:3: Fehler: unbekannter Typname: »class«
/tmp/go-build724218913/github.com/krux02/swig-test/_obj/foo_wrap.c:229:5: Fehler: unbekannter Typname: »class«
[...]
```

the error is obvious, swig tries to build everything as a C library.

to test it, just copy:

```
go get github.com/krux02/swig-test
```

Comment: have you checked http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Go?

Comment: of course. The problem is, that it is not me, who calls swig, so I have no idea where I have to put the -c++ for swig.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [bug report that added Swig support to `go build`](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3258), it looks like it decides how to compile the SWIG wrapper based on the file extension:

- `.swig` files are treated as C
- `.swigcxx` files are treated as C++

If you rename `foo.swig` to `foo.swigcxx`, it should use the correct SWIG flags and compiler.

Answer (score 1):

As documented on http://golang.org/cmd/go/, the -c++ option will be passed to SWIG only if your build file ends with .swigcxx.

Answer (score 0):

See misc/swig/callback in the Go sources for an example of SWIG code that uses C++.